Why the ntpq -c subcmds outputs nothing received, but still can properly sync its time
Environment: RHEL 6.4 with ntp-4.2.6p5-15.el6_10.x86_64 
Question:   the following ntp client can sync its time to the remote ntp server, but why it cannot run the ntpq -c subcmds with the remote ntp server ？ 

# 
# 
# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*10.130.22.10    .GPS.            1 u   17 1024  377    0.859   -0.178   0.428
# 
# 
# ntpq -n -cas 

ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 15314  963a   yes   yes  none  sys.peer    sys_peer  3
# 
# 
# 
# ntpq 
ntpq> as

ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 15314  963a   yes   yes  none  sys.peer    sys_peer  3
ntpq> 
ntpq> 
ntpq> quit
# 
# 
# 
# ntpq 10.130.22.10
ntpq> as
10.130.22.10: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
ntpq> 
ntpq> 
ntpq> pe
10.130.22.10: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
ntpq> 
ntpq> 
ntpq> quit
# 
# 


The remote server's configuration includes a restrict line that applies to your IP address. It might be something like:
restrict default limited kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery

The noquery option would be the one that stops you from getting any status information from the remote server.
It might also be configured to require authentication on remote ntpq and ntpdc requests.
For more information, read the NTP documentation on various restrict options: https://www.ntp.org/documentation/4.2.8-series/accopt/
